# Can I use the Django `URL` template tag inside other logic?

Tags: django, django-templates, templatetags

This is to check that, when a user is anonymous and currently on the login page, they don't see a duplicate login form in the nav (where it would usually be):

```
{% url 'auth_login' as auth_url %}
{% if not auth_url in request.get_full_path %}
    # not on login page, so show login in nav
{% endif %}
```

Does `url` have to be used separately first? Or can it be used in-line with the `if`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to check if a user is anonymous then you can use [`is_anonymous`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_anonymous)

Note the documentation states that you should use `is_authenticated` so you may wish to use both.

```
{% if user.is_anonymous %}
    <a href="{% url 'auth_login' %}">Log In</a>
{% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'logout_url' %}">Signed in as {{ user.username }} (Log Out)</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: That is helpful, but I'm after if there's an inline way to use `url` with the `if`. Reworded the content to make it clearer

Comment: @StringsOnFire - AFAIK, there isn't since you need the variable to use within the if statement. Of course, I'm ignoring actually writing them on the same line.